# Accessing an element that is currently being hovered by mouse, from anywhere in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hover, jquery-hover

Is there any way that I can access an element that currently has mouse hovered over it using jquery?

I know that I can access an element by attaching `mouseover` event to an element, but how about when I haven't applied any event to an element and want to access that specific element which is being hovered over by the mouse from any where in the document?

Comment: What exactly is your use case? or why don't you want to attach events to the DOM?

Comment: what is the problem with mouseover?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can attach the `mouseover` event to the `document` and get the current element being hovered by using `event.target`.

Try,

```
$(document).mouseover(function(e){
  console.log($(e.target).attr('id')); // i just retrieved the id for a demo
});
```

Comment: will fire mouse over event all the time, better to  have event gets fired only when you mouse over on elements.may be something like this $('body:not(:empty))'

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/UZHLL/

Answer (score 4):

```
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    evt = e;
}
```

use evt.target to get the element

Comment: Why bother with the `evt = e` line?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i had some reason for that a long time ago that i can't really remember right now, i think i had cross browser issues causing some problems

Comment: Here found some reference `Internet Explorer provides a global object window.event, which references the last event. And before IE9 there are no arguments in the handler.` http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object @AnthonyGrist

Comment: That explains the *first line*, which I understand perfectly well. What I don't get is why you're then storing what you already have in `e` as another variable, `evt`, when there's literally no reason to do so; you can just use `e` afterwards, anywhere you'd use `evt` in your code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Because e is stored locally in the function, even though there is no var infront. evt will be usable globally

Comment: Ok, so you're intending to store the event object as a global (or at least higher scoped) variable, which you can then use in other pieces of code. That's the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yeah exactly, sorry for explaining badly :/

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `window.event`. Even though it is discouraged, all browsers support it, so this is really a matter of registering a dummy event and then it's possible to use `window.event` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The target-attribute of the event object could help you out.
For instance:

```
$('button:first').mouseover(function(e){


   var target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
   console.log(target );// get element that is being hovered over right now

});
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].onmouseover = function(e){

   var target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
   console.log(target);// get element that is being hovered over right now

};
```

When you want to get the element that is registered to the event-dispacher you have to use the currentTarget-attribut instead. Hope this helps a little bit.